# результат Ajax запроса присвоить в php переменную

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть два файла

`index.php`, `server.php`

В файле `index.php`

Есть список

```
<select size="3" name="abonents" id="abonents">
    <option  value="2938">2938</option>
    <option  value="3781">3781</option>
    <option  value="3591">3591</option>
</select>
```

Блок

```
<div id="block"></div>
```

Ajax запрос

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#abonents").click(function(){
         var a = $("#abonents").val();
         $.post('server.php', {id:a}, function(data){           
                $("#block").text(data);
            });
         });
    });
</script>
```

При клике на список пердается значение методом `POST` в файл `server.php` и
    в блок поставляется данные из Ajax запроса

Файл `server.php`

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST['id'])){   

// ...
// Запрос к БД, возвращет массив $result
// ...

echo print_r($result);  
}
?>
```

На данный момент выводятся данные виде текста

Как мне передать данные Ajax запроса (значение `Data`) в PHP массив для дальнейшей обработки в файле `index.php`?

Comment: В сам `index.php` передать не получится. Можно вернуть значения в `javascript` функцию, которая отправила `ajax` запрос.

Comment: @Pyramidhead а можно по подробней

Comment: А почему не получится передать в `index.php` ?

Comment: Потому, что к моменту отправки `ajax` запроса `index.php` уже отработал. Собственно, результатом его работы является страница, которую он вывел.

Comment: в серверном файле сделайте `echo json_encode($result)`, а обработчикае ajax-а получите его обратно `var values = JSON.parse($data)`

Comment: @teran а как потом значение `values` передать в `php` переменную?

Comment: Никак. По тем причинам, которые я описал выше. Это лишь пример того, как вернуть результат в `javascript`.

Comment: @Xfirab никак, PHP-код на этот момент уже давно отработал и вывел страницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

массив `$result`, который вы выводите с помощью функции `print_r()` необходимо преобразовать в JSON, или XML, либо в любой другой формат по вашему желанию и вывести.

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Возможно, вам потребуется указания и других параметров функции [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php).

Также перед этим неплохо будет указать, что возвращаете вы json данные, для этого использовать заголовки:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

На стороне `index.php` результат ajax запроса преобразуете обратно в массив с помощью `JSON.parse()`.

```
$.post('server.php', {id:a}, function(data){  
    var arrayData = JSON.parse(data);
    // и далее обработать массив значений.
});
```

Вернуть результат и передать его для дальнейшей обработки в PHP-код файла `index.php` не получится. Так как файл этот код уже выполнен,  и показанная страница является непосредственным результатом его работы. Поэтому у вас есть два пути. Реализовать логику полученных данных с помощью `JS`. Либо обращаться к `server.php` непосредственно в коде самого `index.php`. Тут может быть несколько вариантов решения проблемы в зависимости от того, где находятся данные файлы. Возможно если на одном сервере, то вы сможете сделать `include` нужного файла, либо если такой вариант не подходит, то сформировать `GET` запрос с помощью функций `curl` либо `file_get_contents()` выполнить и дождаться его непосредственно во время выполнения `index.php`.

в последнем случае вы получаете тот-же кодированный в `JSON` формат массив значений, и раскодируете его обратно:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('/server.php',.....));
foreach($result as $r){
   ...
}
```

Относительно формирования остальных параметров `file_get_contents` для передачи POST запроса и подстановки параметро это отдельный вопрос, который тут обсуждался совсем недавно.

Осталось заметить, очевидный вариант, когда файл `server.php` отдает вам не массив данных, а сформированный html-код, который вы и отображаете на своей странице. Это и есть самый обычный способ работы с ajax-ом

Comment: Я хотел обрабатывать результирующий массив средствами `PHP`, увы придется с попробовать с помощью `JS` :-(

Comment: @Xfirab я обновил ответ. Если вам работать надо с массивом в пхп, то и запрашивать данные через JS смысла нет.

Comment: Просто я хотел при выборе из списка не перезагружая страницу получить массив данных из БД

Comment: @Xfirab тогда еще раз обновите мой ответ :) возвращайте из `server.php` не массив, а формируйте там непосредственно html-код, который необходимо отобразить. Если имете доступ к этому файлу конечно, и можете его редактировать.

Comment: teran как раз точно подметили, что передается сформированный html-код. Спасибо за пояснения )

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php   
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    if (isset($_POST['id'])){   
     ///  
      echo json_encode($result);
    }
    ?>
  js:
    var values = JSON.parse(data)
```